# How do I create a histogram which can be used for calcBackProject in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have specified the histogram as

```
MatND skinCrCbHist =Mat::zeros(Size(256,256),CV_8UC1);

ellipse(skinCrCbHist, Point(113, 155.6), Size(283.4, 159.2), 43.0, 0.0, 360.0, Scalar(255), -1); // Using a really big ellipse to find any sort of back projection in CrCb domain.

cvtColor(src, ycrcb, CV_BGR2YCrCb); //src is input, image of a person
float crrange[]={0,255};
float cbrange[]={0,255};
const float* ranges[]={crrange,cbrange};
int channelsy[]={1,2};
calcBackProject( &ycrcb, 1, channelsy, skinCrCbHist, backproj, ranges, 255, true );
imshow("bp",backproj);
```

The problem i face is that backproj shows a completely black image.
When I used a normal histogram created with calcHist on a natural image, i do get some sort of backprojection. But how do i use a histogram, i create artificially, by specifying an ellipse, to get a backprojection.

Comment: Could you specify what you're trying to do by "specifying an ellipse"? It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Aurelius : The purpose of drawing ellipse is to specify the 1's in the histogram. The histogram is 256x256 in size. And the ellipse shows which are tones in crcb space which i want to be backprojected.

Comment: Are you sure about your histogram? AFAIK histogram is 1D array (with several channels possibly), but not really an 2D matrix, as in your code. Check the calcHist output for correct dimensions and type.

Comment: @jnovacho :
For a histogram created with calcHist and which is giving backprojection :  
channels : 1
dims : 2
rows : 256
cols : 256
For the skinCrCbHist:
channels : 1
dims : 2
rows : 256
cols : 256

Only skinCrCbHist does not give any backprojection.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you could use mask with the original calcHist function.

You didn't specified which version of OpenCV you are using, so I will assume the latest 2.4.6.0. The method prototype is following (omitting defaults, and types):

`calcHist(images, nimages, channels, mask, hist, dims, histSize, ranges)`

The third parameter is `mask`. The mask means, that the function will ignore all pixels which matches zero pixels in mask. In program the mask is another image correctly setup.

Here is pseudo-code for you problem:

```
1) get input image
2) create matrix of same size as input of type CV_8UC1 filled with zeros
3) draw white (value 255) ellipse on the new image
4) call caclHist with the new image as mask
```

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html

Comment: I think my representation of the question is not clear. The ellipse is the histogram in skinCrCbHist, ellipse is not the mask.

I am basically trying to this efficiently :
http://spottrlabs.blogspot.in/2012/01/super-simple-skin-detector-in-opencv.html

my thinking is that it can be done efficiently using calcbackproj, For this i need to make a histogram over the crcb domain, this histogram looks like an ellipse. 
Then backproject images using this histogram to find skin areas.